# Run Time Error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

> Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set

My code is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim MenuBar As CommandBarButton
  Set MenuBar = CommandBars(Standard).Controls(3)
  MsgBox MenuBar.Caption
End Sub
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Can't see how you're getting that. Should be `Error 9: Subscript out of range`.

Answer (score 3):

You have put `Standard` instead of `"Standard"`. And hence I always suggest to use `Option Explicit`.

If you don't use the `"` then `Standard` is treated as a variable.